# Unable to locate android date picker element

Tags: java, android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I m working on Android Web App automation using Appium and Selenium in Java. 'NoSuchElementException' is displayed when I tried to click mobile element to select a date. Please find my code below and let me know how to handle this.

```
class openBrowser() {   
public static WebDriver driver;   
public static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> androidDriver;   
@Test   
public static void launchBrowser(){   
desiredCapabalities(...);   
androidDriver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new 
URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub", desiredCapabilities));    
driver = androidDriver;   
}

class pickDate() {    
MobileElement element;
try{    
element = (MobileElement) 
androidDriver.findElementByXPath("//android.view.View[@content-desc='28 May  2017']").click();   
}catch(Exception e) { 
throw e; 
}  
}
```

Device details:
Lenovo A6000, OS Version: 5.0.2
Date picker screenshot:[Date Picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgFbP.jpg)

Kindly suggest me any solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try this?  Thread.sleep(5000); 
  driver.findElement(By.xpath(//android.view.View[contains(@content-desc,'28 May']").click();

Comment: Nope... dint worked

Comment: I have opened the same screen and my code works with the same xpath. Is your Android SDK updated?

Comment: Still same exception... is the driver setup is proper in above code ?

Comment: Fyi... SDK is newly installed in last week

Comment: You desired capabilities has only desiredCapabalities(...);    ?

Comment: below are my desiredCapabilities..        `desCapabilities.setCapability("device", mobileDevice);
   desCapabilities.setCapability("app", mobileBrowserName);
   desCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "mobilePlatform");
   desCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "5.0.2");
   desCapabilities.setCapability("platformName", "mobilePlatformName");
   desCapabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "mobileDeviceName");
   desCapabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", "mobileStartupTimeOut");`

Comment: is the driver setup is proper in above code ?

Comment: No, check example of appium on google. The values are incorrect. Some of the values should not be in quotation.

Comment: Below are mandatory and i removed other capabilities...    `desCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.android();desCapabilities.setCapability(BrowserType.CHROME, "Chrome");
   desCapabilities.setCapability("android", Platform.ANDROID);
   desCapabilities.setCapability("deviceName", mobileDeviceName);
   desCapabilities.setCapability("app", mobileBrowserName);   desCapabilities.setCapability("browserConnectionEnabled", true);`

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to click a date input field and then handle the datepicker. You can better input the date directly into the date input field:

```
dateInputField.sendKeys("20-08-1985");
```

Comment: Didn't do anything, or gave an unexpected result?

Comment: above line of code gets passed... but, in mobile, text is not entered.